# How to set the limit of string in property

Tags: c#, console-application

I run out of ideas i don't know what to do down here
I need to make string Course Name outputs a message when it's longer than let's say 100 characters based in input of user

```
public string CourseName
    {
        get { return courseName; }
        set
        {
            if (courseName>value)//I can't fix this one
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have typed more than 50 characters");
            }
            else
            {
                courseName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you using this property? Because `Console.WriteLine` will do nothing to help the user if this is being used in a web application or a WPF app...

Comment: I tried to convert string to int, i tried to do it with arrays, please if you tell me. As for that part I am sure that I didn't do it right if it was right why would I be here

Comment: @d4shm1r - You don't want to convert the string to an int... you want to use the `Length` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh it's just a console app in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check how many characters long a string is you check its `.Length` -property.

So `value.Length > 100` to check if the incoming `value` is over 100 characters long.

Comment: That would check the backing field that is still assigned the old value. Did you mean `value.Length`?

Comment: yes, you're right - fixing

Comment: Please don't forget `null` handling for `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string CourseName
{
    get { return courseName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null && (value.Length > 50))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have typed more than 50 characters");
        }
        else
        {
            courseName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string's length exceed the max, you will need to use the `Length` property of the string class, it contains the length of the string in characters, e.g.:

```
if (value.Length > 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have typed more than 50 characters");

    return;
}
courseName = value;
```

Note that you will also need to handle `null` input, sins string is a nullable type.

So you might want to do something like:

```
if (value == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The course name can not be null.");
}
else if (value.Length > 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have typed more than 50 characters");
}
else
{
    courseName = value;
]
```